# How to decode JSONL from json file and store at struct on golang

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have some json file from amazon s3 and that data store in JSONL format aka json line object without comma

```
this is company.json file
```

```
{"company_id":"112377","people_id":"9a0f6163-d731-389b-a506-5bd54310fb25","name":"Sandy Carter","linkedin":"http://www.linkedin.com/in/sandyacarter","job_title":"VP","image_bucket_url":"https://fct-dataplatform-people-avatar-prod-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_0597ba9b-4b01-e1b0-9345-4f76762807d0/bd7e95668161f4c627f488b9dcbaa903"}
{"company_id":"105651","people_id":"6a513c45-cb8c-3d4b-a395-58c43b542c2b","name":"Ivan Yamshchikov","linkedin":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/kroniker/","job_title":"AI evangelist","image_bucket_url":"https://fct-dataplatform-people-avatar-prod-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_0ec18e53-9f0e-c820-6158-a8a26f4fba7e/22c0b52978e2f7d9787c1eb5821aa68e"}
{"company_id":"102881","people_id":"0d8c9556-fa23-3568-a35c-db2bd4108547","name":"Justin Wainwright","linkedin":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/justin-wainwright-910639106/","job_title":"DevOps Engineer","image_bucket_url":"https://fct-dataplatform-people-avatar-prod-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_925f20fc-c0e5-0f95-67e3-3ccd9f026a3b/e36a5cdca01b5600b3a89bcd6f593e54"}
{"company_id":"112377","people_id":"83ecc6d8-d34d-37af-a67f-c55f7e96e40c","name":"Boaz Ziniman","linkedin":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/bziniman/","job_title":"Technical Evangelist","image_bucket_url":"https://fct-dataplatform-people-avatar-prod-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_d8ea77c4-591f-465f-a825-9e734f2a08fe/62abb82b1e4ecba89549f07aa4c40858"}
{"company_id":"113474","people_id":"7ba4ee0a-f3d9-3431-9e46-983fcfe3ae97","name":"Feng Yu","linkedin":"http://www.linkedin.com/in/mryufeng","job_title":"Researcher"}
```

Now I parse this JSON file and store it on my golang struct. I was trying to extract data from the json file. But I am struggling to decode the json data. I saw `go-simple-serializer` package but the documentation is not that much clear.

Comment: You should use json.Decoder for this, or use one of the available libraries. I wrote this library some time ago for these types of JSON serializations: https://github.com/bserdar/jsonstream

Comment: I  could just use json decoder like this ```jsonFile, err := os.Open("/home/asad/go/src/codemen.org/json-dump-data/people/people.json")
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
 }
but i will only decode the first json object. how could I decode all json data object
 var people People

 if err := json.NewDecoder(jsonFile).Decode(&people); err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("%v", err)
 }

Comment: Please read the marked duplicates, they all decode multiple, a series of JSON objects from the same source.

Comment: Decoder will stop after the first complete object. Call Decode in a loop until the input ends.